# How to create support/create driver for an unsupported device

Tags: windows, usb, driver

So I basically purchased a USB RGB Light (remote controlled), and the only use for the USB is to power itself.

I want to make more out of this and was wondering if there's a way of adding support/maybe creating a driver so I'm able to install the device and control the RGB lights from my windows PC, which I have created a set plan to write a program to be able to do this but before that, I want it to be recognised/have support to be able to move on further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The driver is just a way to communicate with the device.  Writing a driver just allows you to send messages to a USB device or receive data from it, *if* your device already supports those things.

If you want to add features to your USB device, it will be very difficult.  You would have to open up your device, figure out what chips are used inside, and see if it is possible to reprogram them to add more features while not losing the existing features.  This usually requires a lot of skill.

If your device only uses USB for power, it's unlikely there are even any USB communication chips in there at all.

Comment: I might add that its remote controlled, so should be a way to atleast wirelessly connect to it rather than the remote. Thanks anyways, I realized its gona be difficult, which makes it ever more interesting to work on.

Comment: Yeah, hacking the remote control and adding a USB interface to that seems much more doable.